# How do I revert to the previous permissions for a folder?

Tags: chmod

I changed permission of folder by `chmod -R 775 example` and now I want change it to previous permission mod, but I don't know what was that number instead of `755`.

That folder is my project folder and I config apache for it to show in the web. So I changed its permission and then in web browser I see `"This webpage is not available"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to change previous permission. `chmod -R 775 example` is right one for web and you should checkout ownership by `ls -l`. Then change ownership by `chown owner-user:owner-group directory`